# TypeORM: What is the difference between getRawMany() and getMany()?

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have this code:

```
  let otherParticipants = await chatRoomParticipantRepo
    .createQueryBuilder("chatRoomParticipant")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("chatRoomParticipant.user", "user")
    .select("user.connectionId")
    .where("chatRoomParticipant.chatRoomId = :chatRoomId AND chatRoomParticipant.userId != :userId")
    .setParameters({ chatRoomId: chatRoomId, userId: userId })
    .getRawMany();
```

Which gives me this result:

```
[{user_connectionId: 's7p7bUbzt0wudKcxAAAD'}]
```

If I do it with `getMany()` it gives me empty array:

```
[]
```

I am trying to get the `ID` from `user` which connected to `chatRoomParticipant`, but I cannot do it with this code:

```
  let otherParticipants = await chatRoomParticipantRepo
    .createQueryBuilder("chatRoomParticipant")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("chatRoomParticipant.user", "user")
    .select("user.connectionId")
    .where("chatRoomParticipant.chatRoomId = :chatRoomId AND chatRoomParticipant.userId != :userId")
    .setParameters({ chatRoomId: chatRoomId, userId: userId })
    .getMany(); <-- This gives nothing
```

Why is this happening? I thought `getRawMany()` is just for `SUM, COUNT, etc`. In this case I am trying to get the ID which should work with `getMany()` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you should use `getRawMany()` because you want to select some specified fields of your entity,`getMany()` it returns array of entities concern

Comment: @Musilix it means that the ```getMany()``` return the list entities ( in a basic way the columns you defined in the entity class )

Comment: man I'm having a hard time with this junk :/

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is that a call to getMany() doesn't work when I'm trying to select ONLY the columns of entity B for an inner join between some Entity A and Entity B. When I try to select some columns of Entity B after an inner join of Entity A and B, I have to use getRawMany() in order to properly return the columns of Entity B that I need. Your explanation of getRawMany() and getMany() don't help clarify this issue at all sadly.

Answer (score 5):

There are two types of results you can get using select query builder: entities and raw results. Most of the time, you need to select real entities from your database, for example, users. For this purpose, you use getOne and getMany. However, sometimes you need to select specific data, like the sum of all user photos. Such data is not a entity, it's called raw data. To get raw data, you use getRawOne and getRawMany.

- refer to Typeorm documentation.

Hope it is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

getMany(); <-- This gives nothing

Because you don't have single entity for multiple column select

```
.leftJoinAndSelect("chatRoomParticipant.user", "user")
.select("user.connectionId")
```

That's why getMany() is returning blank

getRawMany() is returning value because it's not require any specific naming convention or Entity file's column

**If you want match your select column name with exact entity column name then use**

```
.select("user.connectionId", "connectionId")
.addSelect("dep.branchName", "branchName")
```